# How can I programmatically reorder active menu items?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have an 'audience' menu which has 4 links. When a user visits one of these links, it becomes active, and I want to push it to the front of the menu item list. Outcomes would like like;

```
Pitchers | Catchers | Hitters | Coaches
Coaches (active) | Pitchers | Catchers | Hitters
Catchers (active) | Pitchers | Hitters | Coaches
Hitters (active) | Pitchers | Catchers | Coaches
```

How can I accomplish this programmatically? I can't seem to find the right theme_ or hook_ api function to pull this off.

I've tried this, and changing the '#original_link' weight didn't seem to make a difference (note, I have other things going on here):

```
function apple_menu_link__menu_audience_gateway(&$vars) {
  $element = $vars['element'];
  $submenu = '';

  if($element['#original_link']['in_active_trail'] == TRUE) {
    $element['#original_link']['weight'] = 50;
  }

  if ($element['#below']) {
    unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
    $submenu = '<ul class="nav">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $submenu . '</li>';
}
```

Also, I'm using Panels, Panels Everywhere, Page Manager, and MiniPanels — this could inform the ultimate solution.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

Make **sure** you declare the function with the & in front of items argument, this is what allows the function to modify the $items array passed to the function:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items)
```

In your function you can access every menu item in an array structure like so:

```
   $items['node/%/edit/schedulenew'] = array(
            'title' => 'Schedule1',
            'access callback'=>'user_access',
            'access arguments'=>array('view cssswitch'),
            'page callback' => 'cssswitch_schedule',
            'page arguments' => array(1),
            'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
            'weight'=>4,
        );
```

If you just redefine the 'weight' property, it will allow you to re-order your menus.

- Be sure to clear your cache after each menu changes, or go to the menu page, load the menu edit page and save it, this also rebuilds the menu.

Comment: I'm under the impression that hook_menu() and hook_menu_alter() are only invoked when Drupal rebuilds the menus. When a user visits one of the links it becomes 'active' and then I want it to reorder based on that interaction — not based on menu rebuilds.

My post may not be clear enough: suggest an edit?

Comment: Also, I'm using Panels Everywhere (& Page Manager, MiniPanels), which may alter the ultimate solution.

Comment: I saw your edit. You would need js for this, it seems. There is possibly a module that does something similar you could check the code for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks @stefgosselin. After 5 years of Drupaling, this is one of a handful of times Drupal hasn't had a straight-forward way of doing something. Maybe I'll package this into a module!